# What is the algorithm for ARJ encrypted files?

Tags: encryption, decryption, compression

I came across some password protected ARJ files.
What is the algorithm for ARJ encrypted files ? How to decrypt them ?

Comment: 7-Zip seems to support ARJ files, so you could look into it’s source to see how the encryption key is derived from the password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By going to the [vendor's site](http://www.arjsoftware.com/files.htm) and [looking up the manual](http://sima.cat/ZIP/ARJ.282/ARJ.TXT), I found the different types of "encryption" they used:

```
       "0" indicates XOR garbling (archives created before 2.60).

       "1" indicates XOR garbling (archives created at 2.60 and greater).

       "2" indicates GOST encryption with a 32 byte password limit.

       "3" indicates GOST encryption (ARJCRYPT.COM version 2.1).

       "4" indicates 40 bit encryption limit.
```

GOST:

```
       This version of ARJ provides a new encryption scheme based upon
       the Russian encryption algorithm (GOST 28147-89 cipher).  This
       algorithm is similar in design to DES; however, GOST is designed
       for software implementation.  GOST 28147-89 uses a 256 bit key
       and 32 rounds of encryption.  This implementation uses the 64
       bit cipher feedback mode.
```

You will have to read the rest of the manual because there are numerous configurations for the encryption used that might affect you.

Wikipedia entries for [GOST Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST_(block_cipher))